# If a body is subjected to a force, will it perfectly transmit that force to another body with which it is in contact?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Like if I push a block, which is in contact with another block and so on, will all the blocks experience the same force? (They're piled on top of one another like a tower and this is a parallel force, sort of like a shear situation)

Comment: Do you mean something like a vertical stack of blocks, with a horizontal force applied on one of the blocks?

Comment: Of course not. The parlor trick of pulling a tablecloth from a table stacked with dishes wouldn't work were this true. Nor would the game Jenga. Nor would gently applying the breaks to ones car. And nor would learning how to make your car drift.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the answer is no.

Forces involve the interaction of two objects (A and B) via some type of field. When objects touch macroscopically there is actually an interaction of the electromagnetic fields of the molecules of one object with the molecules of the other. That force at one touching point between A and B is different from an interaction force of B touching a different object C.

We can quickly see this by considering three objects of differing masses. If the objects remain at rest with respect to each other, they must all have the same acceleration and velocity as one another. With different accelerations, they would quickly have different velocities and wouldn't stay together. Now, we specified that they have different masses, so by Newton's 2nd Law that means the net force on each must be different.

If the blocks are stacked vertically and you push the bottom block horizontally, the only force which keeps the top block moving with the bottom is a single friction-based force. A carefully-draw free-body diagram will show that the pushing force on the bottom block is not equal to the force on the top block.

Comment: It would be nice to know what's unhelpful!

Comment: I don't know, i found this pretty helpful

Answer (score 0):

If the force is not enough to move the system, the situation is similar to a cantilever beam fixed at one end (the ground in this case). And there is an applied force at a distance from the end.

There will be shear stresses behind the block where the force is applied. Above that block there will be no shear stress.

Of course there are also the normal stresses from the blocks weight, but I think the OP is interested in the shear stresses.

So, the blocks will not experience the same force.

Comment: Why is the maximum shear stress at the surface

Comment: Wrong. Moment is maximum there, not the shear stresses. I edited the answer correcting it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i don't understand your edited answer

Comment: The force is resisted by the ground. So, all shear stresses are between the ground and the point where the force is applied..